To show: $\Vert x_j \Vert=1, \Vert x_ j -\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{m}k_ix_i \Vert\ge1 $

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional normed space. Then there is a basis $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_m\}$ of $X$ such that for each $j=1,...,m$, $$\Vert x_j \Vert=1, \Vert x_ j -\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{m}k_ix_i \Vert\ge1 $$ for all $k_i\in\mathbf K$.

I have already proved this result: Let $Y$ be a finite dimensional proper subspace of a Normed Linear Space $X$. Then there is some $x\in X$ with $\Vert x \Vert =1$ and $dist (x,Y)=1$.
Please help me to figure out how to use the result to prove the above. Thank you !!!
N.B. Here $k_i$'s are fixed, once it is chosen.

What is the K you are mentionning? Are the $k_i$ fixed? It seems you can construct these with the latter property

Also note that if your $k_i$ are not fixed then the x_i you have automatically form a basis

No, the $k_i$'s are fixed and $K$ is a scalar field, it may be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

It seems your result can be derived from the Hahn-Banach theorem. Since $X$ is already finite-dimensional, is this truly relevant to the problem?

@needmoremath, actually this problem is included in the "Normed linear Space " chapter, before Hahn-Banach and Hilbert.

@Pro_blem_finder oh I see.

@Pro_blem_finder I suspect you might need additional restrictions on the Banach space, particularly something like a strictly convex space. Could you elaborate on the source of the problem?

@needmoremath, Balmohan Limaye, Functional Analysis, Normed space, Problem 5-9

@Pro_blem_finder Thank you for the reference. Just made a solution for the original problem.

Additionally, as I see the original reference, it seems we can show that the statement holds for arbitrary $( k_i )$s.

As stated in the textbook, we assume $\mathbb{K}$ to be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. We regard $\mathbb{K}$ as a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space equipped with the norm induced by the absolute value.

Let $\{ y_j \}_{j=1}^m$ be a basis of the finite-dimensional normed space $X$ (denoted as f.d.n.s), with each basis vector satisfying $\|y_j\| = 1$.
Step 1. We first show that the following set
in $\mathbb{K}^m$ is compact:
$$
S = \{ (a_1,\ldots a_m) \in \mathbb{K}^m : \| a_1y_1 +\cdots a_m y_m \| \leq 1 \}\,.
$$
$\because)$ Note that the operator $\mathcal{T}: (a_1, \ldots, a_m) \in \mathbb{K}^m \mapsto a_1y_1 + \cdots + a_m y_m \in X$ is a linear bijection between normed spaces. Therefore, its inverse $\mathcal{T}^{-1}$ is also linear and thus continuous because $X$ is f.d.n.s. Note also that all norm-induced topologies on f.d.n.s $\mathbb{K}^m$ are equivalent.
Consequently, since a closed unit norm ball $\overline{U(0,1)}$ is compact in f.d.n.s $X$, a set $S = \mathcal{T}^{-1}\Big(\overline{U(0,1)}\Big)\subset \mathbb{K}^m$, the continuous image of a compact set, is also compact. $\blacksquare$

Next, consider the set $S^m \subset (\mathbb{K}^m)^m$. Note that, up to isomorphism $(\mathbb{K}^m)^m \approx \mathbb{K}^{m \times m}$. Thus, let us treat $S^m \subset \mathbb{K}^{m \times m}$. The set $S^m$ is compact and represents the following set of matrices:
$$
S^m = \{ (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times m} : \|a_{i1}y_1 + \cdots + a_{im} y_m \| \leq 1,\: \forall i \in [m] \}.
$$
Step 2. We show that there exists a matrix $\pmb{L} = (l_{ij}) \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times m}$ that maximizes the absolute value of the determinant in $S^m$. Formally:
$$
|\mathrm{det}(\pmb{L})| = {\mathrm{max}}_{\pmb{A}\in S^m} |\mathrm{det}(\pmb{A})| \quad(\pmb{L} \in S^m)\,.
$$
$\because)$ The determinant is a continuous function, being a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Since $S^m$ is compact, the image $\mathrm{det}(S^m) \subset \mathbb{K}$ is also compact, and thus closed and bounded. Therefore, there exists a matrix $\pmb{L} = (l_{ij}) \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times m}$ that maximizes the absolute value of the determinant in $S^m$. $\blacksquare$

We now define a new basis $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$ by setting $x_i = \sum_{j=1}^m l_{ij} y_j$. Note that $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is linearly independent, since $|\mathrm{det}(\pmb{L})| \geq |\mathrm{det}(\pmb{I})| $ $= 1 > 0$.
Additionally, $\|x_i\| = 1$ for all $i$; otherwise, we could rescale $l_{ij}$ for a specific $i$ to achieve a larger determinant, contradicting the maximality.
Step 3. We show that the constructed basis $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$ satisfies the given condition for any $\{\tilde{k}_i\} \subset \mathbb{K}$.
$\because)$ Suppose the contrary: there exists $\{k_i\} \subset \mathbb{K}$, or equivalently $\pmb{k} \in \mathbb{K}^m$, and $q \in [m]$ such that $\| (1+k_q) x_q - \sum_{i=1}^m k_i x_i \| < 1$. Then, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
\big\|\sum_{j=1}^m \big(\underline{\sum_{i=1}^m((1+k_q)\delta_{qi} - k_i)l_{ij}}\big) y_j \big\| < 1, \\
\big\| \sum_{j=1}^m \underline{l_{ij}} y_j \big\| = \|x_i\| = 1 & \text{for } i \in [m] \setminus \{q\}.
\end{cases}
$$
Define $\tilde{\pmb{L}} := \pmb{L} + \pmb{e}_q\big((1+k_q)\pmb{e}_q - \pmb{k}\big)^\top \pmb{L}$. Then $\tilde{\pmb{L}} \in S^m$. However, by calculating the determinant, we arrive at a contradiction:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{det}(\tilde{\pmb{L}}) &= \mathrm{det}(\pmb{L}) \,\mathrm{det}\big(\pmb{I} + \pmb{e}_q\big((1+k_q)\pmb{e}_q - \pmb{k}\big)^\top\big) \\
&= \mathrm{det}(\pmb{L}) \, (1 + 1 + k_q - k_q) \tag{[1]} \\
&= 2\mathrm{det}(\pmb{L}),
\end{align}
$$
contradicting the assumption that $|\mathrm{det}(\pmb{L})|$ is maximal in $S^m$. $\blacksquare$
[1]: Weinstein–Aronszajn identity

Thank you, we can proceed since it is given finite-dimensional.

Exactly. In a separable Hilbert space, this result likely holds as well, given the countable orthonormal basis. However, seems further discussion is needed to extend this to more general spaces.

yeah, we need  to think for Banach space setup...
